# Событие перед закрытием всплывающего окна в JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, события

Во всплывающем окне заполняется некоторая форма. Нужно запретить пользователю закрытие этого окна пока данные не будут заполнены. Какое событие происходит перед закрытием окна?

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните что Вы имеете ввиду под «всплывающим окном»? Модальное окно браузера или специфичное окно из какого-либо фреймворка?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае лучше реализовать окно не window а div, который полностью на JavaScript. Тогда мы 100% (если не уберут окно в отладчике, но это уже хак) можем запретить пользователю дальнейшую работу с сайтом пока он не заполнил все необходимые поля. Т.е у div будет только один метод для закрытие - сабмит формы.

Answer (score 0):

Учтите, что запретить совсем вам не получится, пользователь сможет уйти со страницы, по сути это предупреждение с открытием вашего сообщения и кнопками "Остаться на странице" и "Закрыть":

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Пожалуйста заполните все поля';
};
```